# In CircleCI + Rspec, why does my filter return an empty ActiveRecord::Relation[] only after appending a where clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, circleci

Note: This feature works properly on my local site and in review apps AND passes in rspec locally, but seems to only fail when testing in CircleCI.

Below I have a filter class that I use to pass in a default scope (`Object.where(state: :in_progress)`), and uses a filter parameter to further filter the default scope. This class is called when hitting an endpoint ex: `/api/example/endpoint?filter=current_user` and while testing this endpoint I've found this bug. In my other specs I've validated the data of the objects being queried, the current_user, and the filter param and have been able to narrow down the issue to the call to `apply: ->(scope, user)`. I have verified that `scope` remains valid even after passing it into `apply`, but when the `where` clause is appended `scope` becomes an empty `ActiveRecord::Relation` as if the data never existed at all. I suspect there is either a bug with rspec or something about rspec that I do not understand.

```
class WorkOrderPreviews::IndexFilter
  FILTERS = {
    current_user_filter: {
      apply?: ->(params) {
        params[:filter] == "current_user"
      },
      apply: ->(scope, user) {
        scope.where(technician: user)
      }
    }.freeze,
  }.freeze

  def call(scope, params, current_user)
    FILTERS.keys.inject(scope.dup) do |current_scope, filter_key|
      filter = fetch_filter(filter_key)
      filter[:apply].call(current_scope, current_user) if filter[:apply?].call(params)
    end
  end

  def fetch_filter(filter_key)
    FILTERS.fetch(filter_key) { raise ArgumentError, 'Unknown filter.' }
  end
end
```

My spec:

```
let_once(:tenant) { create_new_tenant }
let!(:staff) { tenant.owner }
let!(:tech) { FactoryBot.create(:staff, :technician) }
let!(:assigned_work_order) { FactoryBot.create(:work_order, :in_progress, technician: tech) }
let!(:unassigned_work_order) { FactoryBot.create(:work_order, :in_progress) }
let!(:estimate) { FactoryBot.create(:work_order, :estimate) }

before do
  host! tenant.hostname
  @access_token, refresh_token = jwt_and_refresh_token(tech.user, "user")
end

context 'without user filter' do
  it 'should respond with all work orders with stat=in_progress' do
    get api_internal_work_order_previews_path,
        headers: { "Authorization" => @access_token }

    expect(assigns(:work_orders)).to eq([assigned_work_order, unassigned_work_order])
  end
end

context 'with user filter' do
  it 'should respond with the assigned work order when ?filter=current_user' do
    scope = WorkOrder.where(state: 'in_progress')
    filtered_results = WorkOrderPreviews::IndexFilter.new.call(scope, { filter: 'current_user' }, tech)

    get api_internal_work_order_previews_path,
        headers: { "Authorization" => @access_token },
        params: { filter: "current_user" }

    expect(assigns(:work_orders)).to eq(filtered_results)
  end
end

# This is the reponse body for spec #1. This data (which excludes the filter) is correct. 
(byebug) JSON.parse(response.body)
[{"id"=>4, "advisor"=>nil, "technician"=>"Firstname5 Lastname5", "due_in_time"=>nil, "due_out_time"=>nil, "total_ro_billed_hours"=>0, "label"=>nil, "vehicle_plate_number"=>"JC2931", "vehicle_fleet_number"=>"12345", "vehicle_year"=>"1996", "vehicle_make"=>"Toyota", "vehicle_model"=>"T100", "vehicle_color"=>"BLACK", "vehicle_engine"=>"V6, 3.4L; DOHC 24V", "service_titles"=>[]}, {"id"=>5, "advisor"=>nil, "technician"=>nil, "due_in_time"=>nil, "due_out_time"=>nil, "total_ro_billed_hours"=>0, "label"=>nil, "vehicle_plate_number"=>"JC2931", "vehicle_fleet_number"=>"12345", "vehicle_year"=>"1996", "vehicle_make"=>"Toyota", "vehicle_model"=>"T100", "vehicle_color"=>"BLACK", "vehicle_engine"=>"V6, 3.4L; DOHC 24V", "service_titles"=>[]}]
(byebug)
```

I found this bug while testing if `response.body` returned the correct collection, and to further prove the point of this post I'm including the spec above. Weirdly enough, `filtered_results` returns the correct data, but the same call in my controller returns the empty `ActiveRecord::Relation`. The only thing I can think of is that maybe the user session in CircleCI is instantiated in a different way than when running locally, but this seems unlikely. What am I missing?

Comment: My first thought is your test database doesn't contain the expected test data. Please show us how you're populating your test data, and verify the contents of the test database in your test.

Comment: @Schwern thanks for the response! I updated the spec block with my data. I use FactoryBot to create Users (tech is who we care about), and WorkOrder objects. My other specs (not listed here) validate that the data is correct and that the endpoint works as expected otherwise.

Comment: I don't see where the database is populated. You have a bunch of lets to create things, but they don't appear to be used. Your local test database may be dirty.

Comment: @Schwern thanks again for the response. "let!" - with bang - automatically instantiates those objects regardless of how or when they are used so those objects exist in the DB. Confirmed with the passing specs that I've mentioned.

Comment: @AustinsGrumpy are you running your entire test suite locally, with the same options passed to rspec that your CI uses?